# Creating form for multiple enum selection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

Form

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path, html: {multipart: true } do |f| %>

<p>
<%= f.label :source %><br>
<%= f.text_field :source %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :artwork %><br>
<%= f.text_field :remote_artwork_url %>
</p>

<%= f.select :article_type, Article.article_types.keys, {}, class: 'article-article_type-select' %>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>


<% end %>
```

Model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

enum article_type: [:headline, :news, :editorial, :political, :social, :sports, :food] 
scope :by_type, -> { where(article_type: [0..2, 4]) }

end
```

Controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 def new
    if current_user.admin != true
      flash[:danger] = "You are not permitted to sumbit articles!" 
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @article = Article.new
    end
  end  

  def show
    @article = Article.approved.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    if current_user.admin != true
      redirect_to root_url
    else
     @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
     @article.save 
      if @article.errors.any?
       flash[:danger] = "Article failed!"
       redirect_to 'new_article_path'
      else
       flash[:success] = "Article created!"
       redirect_to new_article_path
      end
    end 
  end  

 def index
    @articles = Article.approved.all
 end 

 private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:artwork, :source, :title, :remote_artwork_url, :article_type)
  end

end
```

Schema

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.string   "source"
t.string   "artwork"
t.integer  "article_type"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
t.boolean  "approved",     default: false
end
```

I want to be able to assign multiple enum to each Article. Right now my form only accepts one enum selection and I am not sure if I have to change the table/schema to an array to accept multiple enum selections. Also, I wrote this code a while ago and I no longer remember what `{ where(article_type: [0..2, 4]) }` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns of type enum can only be assigned one value. That's kind of the point of them. If you need to store multiple values, it may be an indication that the data needs remodelling.

```
scope :by_type, -> { where(article_type: [0..2, 4]) }
```

The above query gets all articles with a type 0 or 1 or 2 or 4. It results in a the following query

```
SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE ("articles"."id" = 4 OR "articles"."id" BETWEEN 0 AND 2)
```